# bandwidth usage curl php get headers

Tags: php, curl, header, bandwidth

if i use curl via php to get just header of a url. it's cost to get all content of response bandwidth for my request? or just as lenght of header i get.
my code is something like these:

```
<?php

$url='http://www.yahoo.com';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$header_size = $curl_info[header_size];
$header = substr($buffer, 0, $header_size);

echo $header;
```

Comment: if you want JUST the headers of the response, then issue a `HEAD` http request, not a full `GET` as you're doing. Because, you're downloading the entire response (including the document body) and then throwing away the body.

Comment: @MarcB Actually, he *is* making a `HEAD` request. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `CURLOPT_NOBODY` makes curl send a `HEAD` request, so you're getting just the headers in response, without content.